# What is the proper way of safely shutdown the Xodus environment?

Tags: xodus

I need a way shutting down the Xodus environment so that

- It waits for all the writing transactions in all threads to finish (or be aborted after a timeout as an option).
- It blocks starting new transactions (or throws an exception as an option).
- Safely closes the environment.

So far we tried something like this

```
if (env.isOpen()) {            
    env.clear();
    env.close();
}
```

but I am not sure that it does exactly the right thing, I still get exceptions thrown from `env.close()` from time to time. So what is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that `Environment#clear()` just clears all the data in your environment.

Minor: you don't have to check whether your environment is open before closing it.

If you don't care much of the application state then you can set the `exodus.env.closeForcedly` option on Environment creation:

```
Environment env = Environments.newInstance("db path", new EnvironmentConfig().setEnvCloseForcedly(true));
```

In that case, `close()` method reports in logs the number of not finished at the moment transactions and does close the environment anyway.

Comment: Thanks. What is going to happen to transactions trying to start after the environment is closed? Do I need to manually track and suspend/abort them?

Comment: Attempt to start transaction on a closed Environment will fail with a `ExodusException("Environment is inoperative")`.

Comment: @MikhailPuzanov are you running Xodus on a servlet or servlet-like environment?

Comment: @xybrek I'm running it in a Spring application, so just need to implement some reasonable PreDestroy method.